# What's the per_document consistency like for the search api on the production servers?

Tags: google-app-engine

We are porting our app from **Amazon+ElasticSearch** to **GAE+FTS.**

I was used to deal with the eventual consistency of the **Lucene indexes** while writing tests.

On the local dev server, it seems that all document indexing is fully consistent. I create, update or delete a document and immediately search on it and always get the correct results. The HRD local behaviour correctly (if configured to) simulates the eventual behaviour of the production environment.

From the local behaviour of the **FTS engine**, can I assume something about the production environment? I am not yet able to try it out but, from the deprecation of the globally consistent option, I will assume a certain level of eventual consistency in production.

Anyone has some metrics or experience to share?

Thanks!